# Как работает set()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, списки

Есть код:

```
p1 = [4, 9, 12, 6]
p2 = [4, 9, 12, 6, 8]
print(set(p1))
print(set(p2))
```

---

Вывод:

```
{9, 4, 12, 6}
{4, 6, 8, 9, 12}
```

---

### Почему p1 - не сортирован, а p2 - отсортирован ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Если Вы получили исчерпывающий ответ (а по моему это так), то его нужно принять (поставить напротив зеленую галочку), чтобы закрыть вопрос и отблагодарить человека, который тратил на Вас время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` и не гарантирует, что итерация по нему будет возвращать элементы в каком-то определённом порядке. То, что на каких-то небольших множествах может наблюдаться какая-то упорядоченность - всего-лишь случайность.

Comment: Спасибо, ключевой момент это **всего-лишь случайность**

Answer (score 2):

`set` создаёт множество. Элементы в нём перечислены в случайном порядке. Подробнее см. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset